# compatibility with automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I've been working a little with the new UI options in iOS 7, and the `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets` property in `UIViewController` is really freaking me out. the thing is, either you don't set it, but then you will have to position your scroll views differently in iOS 7 and other iOS versions. the alternative is to set it to `NO` only for iOS 7 and use the same positioning. I don't understand why apple implemented this property at all, in my opinion, good practice would be always having it to `NO` (not having such a property at all), just like it was before. I understand that it is easier to use if you are lazy, but this seems like a really bad programming practice in my opinion. am I missing out on something or do you agree?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't see any problem. iOS 6 SDK does not contain this property. You just should use following code:

```
if([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setAutomaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets:)])
{
   self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
}
```

Comment: thanks, that's a useful method. but do you have any idea about what to use this property for, and why it is YES on default?

Comment: iOS 7 has a translucent navigation bar by default. and developers wanted to make the scroll view visible behind navigation and status bars.